# PANDAS: How to pd.read_csv and split 7 digits integers into 4 by 3 integers?

Tags: python, csv, numpy, pandas, matplotlib

I am a noob to python and pandas however I wish to try my best to learn so here i am, and pls pardon me if I make any mistakes.

I need help. My goal is to plot a csv data containing multiple plot data in a 25414 long list. In order to do that I need to identify which Plot number and what data (Plot Data) goes to the Plot Number (i.e. Heading) from the csv file. After which I will plot using Matplotlib and Numpy all the graph sharing the same axis as seen in the picture. [Plot image sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ITLH.jpg)

1.I have a csv file generated from a sensor and the format is this:-

- Original data = 8790203

  - 8790 = Plot Number (pandas dataframe header)
  - 203 = Data for plotting (Plot Data)

And the data in the csv span up to 25414 long.
[Click here to download csv raw data.....](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7qTBDRT8ydLWXFJX2tVaTAyVVE/view?usp=sharing)

Target List Outcome:

```
[Plot Number]    [Plot Data]
8790             203
8790             205
8790             210
8791             060
8791             065
8791             090
```

The reason I use PANDAS is because it is FAST. And I already tried this code to slice the data but takes forever to complete (due to error or due to inefficient slicing, i am not sure).

```
for x in range(0,len(factor),+1):
y = factor.iloc[x]
PlotNum = y[:4]
PlotData = y[5:]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`read_fwf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html#pandas.read_fwf) and pass the column widths to param `widths`, set `header=None` and pass a list of the desired column names:

```
In [234]:
df = pd.read_fwf(r'c:\data\trace_ff_ID(360).trc', widths=[4,3], header=None, names=['Plot Number', 'Plot Data'])
df.head()

Out[234]:
   Plot Number  Plot Data
0         8790        203
1         8790        204
2         8790        205
3         8790        206
4         8790        207
```

Comment: Hi thank you. I seen read_fwf and thot fwf is just another type of file extension. nvr thot i'd be using it. Thanks! Will try it out soon.

Answer (score 0):

For efficiency use [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) which is highly optimised, then use arithmetic
to split Number and Data :

```
In [10]: df=pd.read_csv('trace_ff_ID(360).csv',header=None)

In [11]: df2=pd.DataFrame({'Plot Number':df[0]//1000,'Plot Data':df[0]%1000})
```

The whole process take 100 ms.